APS - How to get Revit ViewSet
In Autodesk Platform Services, we can access Published Revit Views using "Get List Model Views" (link). That call retrieves the name,role,guid and isMasterView fields, but no information on the published view set of the Revit View.
On the viewer, the bubbleNode as information of the ViewSet, under .data.ViewSets.
What I want to accomplish is to filter the view list by ViewSet without (or before) loading the model on the viewer. If the viewer can access that info, I'm wondering if there is any API or workflow that can get me that information...
Thanks

You can find that information in the manifest.json file.
ie. refer to "ViewSets": "Set 1", in the json below:
  {
                                    "guid": "8ba265ee-debf-4b65-a77a-52060c81238b-00000c66",
                                    "type": "geometry",
                                    "role": "2d",
                                    "name": "Site",
                                    "viewableID": "8ba265ee-debf-4b65-a77a-52060c81238b-00000c66",
                                    "phaseNames": "Project Completion",
                                    "ViewSets": "Set 1",
                                    "status": "success",

Do you know how to retrieve the manifest.json file ?

Can you send me a link with info how to get manifest.json file?

Yes, here it is - https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/developers_guide/basics/translation/
